# How can I write a binary array to a file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, file-io

I have to write the below binary array into a file:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x55, 0xAA, 0x02};
```

I want to put the exact data into the file (55,AA,02). Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381508/can-a-byte-array-be-written-to-a-file-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128674/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-save-a-byte-array-as-a-file-on-disk-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224239/whats-the-best-way-to-write-a-short-array-to-a-file-in-c

Comment: Use BitConverter.ToString(data) to create a string that you can write to a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iirc you can use

```
string content = BitConverter.ToString(data);
```

to retrieve a string containing the content and then write that string to the File you want.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `Stream.Write(byte[] buffer)` overload.

And even easier,

```
   System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("fileName", data);
```

Comment: When i use the aboe function some non readable characters are displayed in the file. I want the data to be displayed exactly.

Comment: It's because you're writing characters, which are not printable. 0x02 is not a 'printable' character code. You want to use a *hex editor* to view your output file and verify it wrote data exactly.

Comment: @user209293 Your data has non-printable codes when viewed a s ASCII/ANSI/UTF8. So you'll have to more precise in what result you want. Currently your comments contradict the req in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\data.bin", FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x55, 0xAA, 0x02 };
bw.Write(data);
bw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Comment: open the output file in microsoft visual studio,u will see the result that what do you want in binary format

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)`.

Comment: When i use the aboe function some non readable characters are displayed in the file. I want the data to be displayed exactly

Comment: @user209293, use a hex editor. Don't expect a text editor to display you non printable characters like 0x02.

Comment: If you don't want to write the exact data, but rather the string representation of your byte values into a file, maybe you should rephrase your question.